# JQuery ajax request - echo will not output result

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, echo

I've never encountered anything this strange before. I raise an Ajax request using jQuery to get a value from mysql.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxClassificationCheck.php?category='+category,
    cache: false,
    success: function(returnClass)
    {
        $("#classification").val(returnClass);
}});
```

and the php...

```
include_once ('functions.php');
connectdb();

$category = $_GET['category'];

$q = "SELECT classification_id FROM sch_category WHERE category_id = $category";

$r = mysql_query($q) or die (mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$classification = $row['classification_id'];
echo $classification;
```

The result in network capture shows the output from the ajax request which is empty.

If I change:

```
echo $classification;
```

to

```
echo "result is $classification";
```

outputs:

```
result is 2
```

It also works with:

```
echo "a".$classification;
```

outputs:

```
a2
```

Is there a minimum character limit on what can be returned via Ajax?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all your suggestions

@RocketHazmat - tried dataType: 'text', still not returning single integer. Definitely using echo $classification;

@dualed - I put the url into the browser window and I get the correct integer response so it is something wrong with my ajax.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to add `dataType: 'text'` to your `$.ajax` call.  Maybe when jQuery just sees a number, it tries to process it.

Comment: You're using `echo $classification;` in your code, not `die($classification);` (or `exit($classification);`), right?

Comment: What do you see if you access the ajax url with your browser?

Comment: You need to use the variable in your query `"SELECT classification_id FROM sch_category WHERE category_id =". $category;`

Comment: @wirey PHP parses strings enclosed in double quotes, so the query is OK in that regard

Comment: @dualed ah ok.. I'm not too familiar with php.. just didn't know you can pass in a variable as a string

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I have edited the question with the results of testing.

Answer (score 2):

In `$.ajax` you have to specify which content-type is expected. In your case it is 'html', so

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  dataType : 'html'
});
```

But instead of this i would recommend to you to use dataType 'json' and change your php script's last line to `json_encode($classification)`. If you do not specify dataType, jQuery will make an intelligent guess and this can result in strange behaviour.

And **please read** something about [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both and it is still not working for me. I will bear this in mind as I don't generally use dataType as without has always worked for me I guess there must be something else amiss here.

Comment: Please post the raw output of your php script.

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure what you mean. The PHP code is above. The output is the integer 1 or 2 when run through the web address (depending on replacement of $category). No output when using ajax, unless using PHP I insert at least one character in front.